# Spinner width not expanding to full width

Tags: android, spinner, android-spinner

I have a spinner and set the spinnerMode to dialog on it so that text will wrap onto a new line on Android 4.2+, but in doing so it causes the information on the spinner not to fill the width. i.e https://i.stack.imgur.com/vLkC9.png. How can I get it to fill the width but also have it wrapping onto a new line on 4.2+?

```
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:spinnerMode="dialog"  />
```

Comment: unless you have a reason to, I would keep it as it is. As users are used to spinners with that size. And if you had a really long item it would cause for the dialog to fill the whole screen

Comment: What do you mean keep it as it is?

Comment: As in the picture you attached, doesn't seem to have any problems in terms of Android design. It's actually probably better as the dialog remains small as it should be

Comment: This is how they are displayed normally. http://i.imgur.com/WKO68bi.png and http://i.imgur.com/R8WV7xc.png is what it looks like on my phone if I have the dialog mode set on the spinner.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the layout in which the spinner is wrapped in is set to:

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
```

In essence this effects the properties of all widgets in that layout.

Hope this helps :)